# How to Know Time Format in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have received some values in my local database tables from another data source.

In that, Arrival Date and Arrival time are formatted like `20120913`. I found the format as `YYYYMMDD`, but for the time I am unable to find which format they used. It's like `2522803`.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is 02:52:28.03? If it's a numeric field the leading 0 would be left off.

Comment: instead of guessing, can you contact the owner of the other source to determine the format?  It might be the easiest option and it would prevent you from formatting it the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe it is a UNIX timestamp, but that strikes me as a bit old?

Comment: There's no real way to guess based on one sample with no corresponding "known" value - if you could find a few examples where someone/something else already knows what time they're meant to represent, we might be able to fathom it.

Comment: Maybe it was ['Star date October 21,  4845, Time: 02:16:48'](http://www.hillschmidt.de/gbr/sternenzeit.htm)

Comment: Can you show some other examples so that we can make some guesses with more than one data point?

Answer (score 0):

2522803 may represent the seconds, then you can check this with the below query :

```
select convert(varchar(8),dateadd(ss,2522803,0),108)
```

I got the result as : 04:46:43

Comment: But, as a number of seconds, that value represents 29days, 4 hours, 46 minutes and 43 seconds. A somewhat unusual "time" value to store. (Your conversion hides the days in the result)

Comment: I had retrieved the HH:MM:SS, since the user asked about the time format.  But I should have given a full description.  Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever.